# GroupBy Python with a custom function

Tags: python, group-by

I need to tranforme my DF.
I have that for many other lines:

```
3   21-TV-0515  ACACIAS     21-TV-0515
4   21-TV-0515  ACACIAS     22-TV-0219
```

I found that:

```
ACACIAS     21-TV-051521-TV-0515    21-TV-051522-TV-0219
```

When i used that code:

```
ConcordanceMAPNOVA.groupby('Acronyme').sum()
```

But in fact I want to have somethings like that:

```
ACACIAS     21-TV-0515         21-TV-0515, 22-TV-0219
or  ACACIAS     [21-TV-0515]    [21-TV-0515, 22-TV-0219]
```

Do you know if it was possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not very clear, but I think you want to aggregate and retain unique values, right? In that case, you could do:

```py
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["21-TV-0515", "21-TV-0515"], "Acronyme": ["ACACIAS", "ACACIAS"], "col2": ["21-TV-0515", "22-TV-0219"]})
df.groupby("Acronyme").agg(set)
```

Or (if you want a list instead of a set): `df.groupby("Acronyme").agg(lambda x: list(set(x)))`

Comment: Yes thanks sorry in english it's hard for me. But this is the result i want exept the fact the result is in { } but it's not really important. Thank you verry much.